# Choosing range of ports in spark

Tags: docker, apache-spark, pyspark

From spark documentation I know that the ports that executors, i.e. workers (because by default there is just one executor per a worker) use for establishing connection with master are randomly determined, but how could I setup their range to publish those ports in docker. Also, if a worker establishes a connection with another container (which is not part of the distributed system), do I need to publish the port on which the worker would get returned data from the container (e.g. via an https request)? 
Just to note, I do not use docker-compose.yml because I do not need the containers to be set as services and I want to add/remove containers when needed by increase/decrease in number of customers.

Comment: Just put all the containers in the same docker network and you don't have to worry about exposing ports.

Comment: There can be many executors per worker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the same docker network for all containers which will communicate with each other. Containers can reach others using container name (on all ports) just like if different hosts on a network.

Create a network (needed only once)

```
docker network create <network_name>
```

when you launch a container use `--network`  to connect container to the network

```
docker run --network=<network_name> --name <container_name> <image>
```

You can also connect existing containers to networks

```
docker network connect <network_name> <container_name>
```

Reference:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/

Comment: What about containers outside the distributed system, e.g. an endpoint communication to an API? Should I publish the ports (e.g. 5000 on endpoint and 46512 on the workers) or I should just publish ports on the endpoint API?

Comment: You only need to expose which will be accessed from outside the docker network. In my hadoop-spark setup I expose ports 8088 on resource manager(to check running job), 50070 on name node container (to check files on hdfs). No other port needs to be exposed as container can communicate with each other on all ports because of the docker network.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by endpoint communication? Are you running additional services (apart from hadoop/spark services) on the container which will be accessed from outside?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. What I mean is, e.g. a spark worker will connect to a container that is running a flask server. I know I need to publish a port on the container containing the flask server, but do I need to publish a port on the spark worker also (so the worker and the container with flask server can communicate)? I hope I have been clearer this time.

Comment: you don't need to publish any ports on spark worker container. You could expose port on your flask container or else connect flask container to the same network (recommended).